# How to pull on information from a JSON response

Tags: selenium-ide

I get the following response from a payload I post using fetch and for the life of me cannot find a way to parse out the information, for example the access token which is required to run by next testcase. I tried lot of different options. Can some help please to point me in the right direction please?

echo: {"access_token":"00D5r0000008j","instance_url":"https://mywebsie.com","id":"https://mywebsite/id/00D5r0000008j6UEAQ/0055r000001aYLmAAM","token_type":"Bearer","issued_at":"1681461844656","signature":"yKCoz4I8J"}

Answer (score 0):

just used Stored Json and it worked, so easy in the end , good tutorial here https://www.qafox.com/selenium/selenium-automation-tutorial/
store json|${typeofobjectreturned}|storedjson
execute script|return ${typeofobjectreturned}.access_token|accesstoken

hope this help someone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: execute async script|return fetch("<url>&client_secret=<secret>&username=<username>&password=<password>&grant_type=password",{   method: 'post',   headers: new Headers({'Cookie':'BrowserId=<browserid>; CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1', 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept':'*/*','Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br'}) }).then(response => response.text());|textresponse     store json|${textresponse}|typeofobjectreturned     execute script|return ${typeofobjectreturned}.access_token|accesstoken